# Using Where statements within Select and a global Where statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run this query. I need to use a where statement within the Select statement but I also need a global Where statement to refine my data to a specific time. This query gives me the error

> "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Invalid column name
>   'TransactionDateTime'."

I know I could add the date Where statement to every line but when I have to change the dates that would be a pain.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select (Select count(Paymentmethod)
from [CLIENT-PROD-POS].dbo.POS_Payments
where paymentmethod ='1') 
as Cash,

(Select count(Paymentmethod)
from [CLIENT-PROD-POS].dbo.POS_Payments
where paymentmethod ='2')
as PaperChecks,

(Select count(Paymentmethod)
from [CLIENT-PROD-POS].dbo.POS_Payments
where paymentmethod ='3')
as CreditCards,

(Select count(Paymentmethod)
from [CLIENT-PROD-POS].dbo.POS_Payments
where paymentmethod ='5')
as EChecks

where TransactionDateTime > '1/1/2015' and transactiondatetime < '2/1/2015'
```

Comment: it looks like SQL Server and not mySQL, correct?

Comment: Of course you get that error. You have a query where each column is a subselect so there is no table as the basis of your query. If you want that as part of the criteria for each subquery you have to add that where clause to each query. And simple grouping would be better in the first place.

Comment: In order to have a global WHERE, you must first have a global FROM.

Comment: Yes it is SQL server. I know I could do that Sean Lange but when I have to change the dates I would have to change all of them. I'm trying to write this so I only have to change the date in one statement not all of them.

Comment: You could also use some variables here so you don't have to hardcode the datevalues over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the error you need to add the `TransactionDateTime` filer in every individual `sub-query`.

You don't need multiple `sub-queries` to count each `paymentmethod`. Try this

```
SELECT Count(CASE WHEN paymentmethod = '1' THEN Paymentmethod END) AS Cash,
       Count(CASE WHEN paymentmethod = '2' THEN Paymentmethod END) AS PaperChecks,
       Count(CASE WHEN paymentmethod = '3' THEN Paymentmethod END) AS CreditCards,
       Count(CASE WHEN paymentmethod = '5' THEN Paymentmethod END) AS EChecks
FROM   [CLIENT-PROD-POS].dbo.POS_Payments
WHERE  TransactionDateTime > '1/1/2015'
       AND transactiondatetime < '2/1/2015'
       AND paymentmethod IN ( 1, 2, 3, 5 )
```

Another way to count this will be

```
sum(case when paymentmethod ='1' then 1 else 0 end) as Cash
```

Comment: @shriop - Updated in answer

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
Select sum(case when paymentmethod = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Cash,
       sum(case when paymentmethod = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as PaperChecks,
       sum(case when paymentmethod = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as CreditCards,
       sum(case when paymentmethod = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as EChecks
from [CLIENT-PROD-POS].dbo.POS_Payments
where TransactionDateTime > '2015-01-01' and
      transactiondatetime < '2015-02-01';
```

I also strongly advise you to use standard formats for the dates -- YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: If not using YYYY-MM-DD format, then at least make the conversion explicit. For SQL Server e.g. **`datetimecol >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/2015',101)`**

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I have made the change. Its been over 15 yrs since I have had to code so I'm a little rusty.